# How to make particles on specific vertices of a model

Tags: modeling

I am rather new to Blender, and very new here.
I have a project which is to make a hangar with a ship inside.
But I am stuck with particles, I would like to make the particles attach to specific vertices, like for instance in this model.
I give you a picture as example.

Thanks in advance for your answer.

[image]

Answer (score 8):

You can use vertex groups for that.

### Setting up the vertex group

Select your mesh and go to the mesh tab. Under Vertex Groups, click the `+` button to create a vertex group:

[image: add vertex group]

In edit mode, select the vertices you want to emit the particles from:

[image: select vertices]

To edit the vertex group, switch to weight paint with the object selected:

[image: weight paint mode]

Then limit the editing to the previously selected vertices by clicking on the Vertex Selection button:

[image: vertex selection button]

Select `Weights>Set Weight` to set the weight of the selected vertices to one.

### Using It In The Particle System

In your particle system, under Source, select Vertices:

[image: emit from vertices]

To make it use the vertex group, go to `Vertex Groups` and change the Density group:

[image: vertex groups]